# I want to dynamically create table(collection)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

**I am using the following code :**

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class CreatingCollection {
   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      //Creating a MongoDB client
      MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
      //Connecting to the database
      MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("test");
      //Creating a collection
      database.createCollection("sampleCollection");
      System.out.println("Collection created successfully");
   }
}
```

**I am getting the following error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder.maxWaitQueueSize(I)Lcom/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder;
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:157)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:58)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.build(MongoClientOptions.java:1734)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:157)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:147)
    at com.ras.db.CreatingCollection.main(CreatingCollection.java:8)
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Use the most recent release of the driver and follow its published documentation.